# Facing issue while adding values to datatable in C# while executing stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a stored procedure which accepts a table type parameter.

```
TableType1
Id int,
Name varchar(50)

Create Procedure [proc1]
    @insertDT TableType1 Readonly,
    @deleteDT TableType1 Readonly
    .....
```

Now I need to pass table-type parameters and execute stored procedure using C# and Entity Framework.

```
private void(List<User> insertUsers,List<User> deleteUsers)
{
    DataTable insertUDT = new DataTable();
    insertUDT.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    insertUDT.Columns.Add("Name ", typeof(string));

    DataTable deleteUDT = new DataTable();
    deleteUDT.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    deleteUDT.Columns.Add("Name ", typeof(string));

    foreach(var row in insertUsers)
    {
        insertUDT.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    foreach(var row in deleteUsers)
    {
        deleteUDT.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    SqlParameter insertUserParams = new SqlParameter("@insertDT ", SqlDbType.Structured)
                 {
                     TypeName = "dbo.[TableType1],
                     Value = insertUDT
                 }

    SqlParameter deleteUserParams = new SqlParameter("@deleteDT ", SqlDbType.Structured)
                 {
                     TypeName = "dbo.[TableType1],
                     Value = deleteUDT
                 }

    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Exec proc1 @insertDT @deleteDT", insertUserParams, deleteUserParams);
}
```

With this code, I get an error

> Incorrect Syntax near @deleteDT.

Please let me know if `deleteUsers` list is empty is causing an issue or if there is a syntax error.

Comment: `TypeName="dbo.[TableType1],...` you never close the quotes `"` that you opened.

Comment: And your parameter names are wrong, too - they both have a trailing space, which they shouldn't have - use `new SqlParameter("@deleteDT",` (**without** a trailing space after the param name!)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue "," is missing while executing the context and it resolved error

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Exec proc1 @insertDT, @deleteDT", insertUserParams, deleteUserParams);
```